# Insert from select: invalid column name... what am I missing here?

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have this simple query:

```
INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT (
name,
ExtensionData
)

values (
Description,
InventoryNumber
)

SELECT top 10 IV.inventorynbr,PT.Description FROM Interchange.dbo.InventoryNbrs IV
inner join powerlink.dbo.part_type PT
on substring(IV.inventorynbr,1,3) = PT.parttype
```

However the 'Description' and 'Inventorynbr' are appearing underlined and when I mouse over them it says 'invalid column name'... (but the columns DO exist!)

[image: Invalid column name]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for this operation is incorrect.

Compare to here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Correct syntax would be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT 
(
  name,
  ExtensionData
)
SELECT TOP 10 PT.Description, IV.inventorynbr 
FROM Interchange.dbo.InventoryNbrs IV
INNER JOIN powerlink.dbo.part_type PT
   ON substring(IV.inventorynbr,1,3) = PT.parttype
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT (name, ExtensionData)
    VALUES (Description, InventoryNumber)
```

`Description` and `InventoryNumber` are *identifiers* not constants.  Presumably, you intend for them to be coming from the following query.

The correct syntax is `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT (name, ExtensionData)
    SELECT top 10 IV.inventorynbr,PT.Description
    FROM Interchange.dbo.InventoryNbrs IV JOIN
         powerlink.dbo.part_type PT
         ON LEFT(IV.inventorynbr, 3) = PT.parttype
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the values clause. That's for inserting literal values.

```
INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT (name, ExtensionData)
SELECT top 10 PT.Description,IV.inventorynbr 
FROM Interchange.dbo.InventoryNbrs IV
inner join powerlink.dbo.part_type PT
on substring(IV.inventorynbr,1,3) = PT.parttype
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two ways of inserting.

`INSERT.. VALUES()` is generally used for inserting a list of hardcoded values

`INSERT.. SELECT` is used for inserting data selected from another table or source.

You want this:

```
INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT (name,ExtensionData)

SELECT top 10 IV.inventorynbr,
              PT.Description 
FROM Interchange.dbo.InventoryNbrs IV
JOIN powerlink.dbo.part_type PT on substring(IV.inventorynbr,1,3) = PT.parttype
```

Side note to keep in mind: you aren't ordering your query so the `top 10` won't be a predictable set of records.

Comment: But the question is... what if I have to insert a few hard coded values along with the data coming from the select? Then I have to insert the data from the select first and THEN run a new query just adding the hard coded stuff?

Comment: @YanKleber, you may use one query usion UNION: INSERT INTO YanDev.dbo.PRODUCT (name,ExtensionData)

SELECT top 10 IV.inventorynbr,
              PT.Description 
FROM Interchange.dbo.InventoryNbrs IV
JOIN powerlink.dbo.part_type PT on substring(IV.inventorynbr,1,3) = PT.parttype UNION select 'first_hardcoded_Name', 'first_hardcoded_descr' UNION select 'second_hardcoded_Name', 'second_hardcoded_descr'